# Stereo Mix does not work

Tags: windows, audio, recording

Stereo Mix no longer seems to work on my computer -- it did once, but now I am unable to receive any sort of audio from it. When trying to record it with programs such as Audacity, it reports that there is an error opening the sound device. Additionally, I can make no changes whatsoever to Stereo Mix, such as with regards to default format, where it simply reports `Format not supported by device`.

I am sure that Stereo Mix had definitely worked in the past, so does anyone have any idea as to why Stereo Mix would suddenly break? (I have no applications taking exclusive control of Stereo Mix)

Stereo Mix's volume meter indicates it is not sending any output.

Comment: Is stereo mix's volume turned to 0?

Comment: Of course not :(

Comment: Did the drivers get updated

Answer (score 1):

If you updated the sound driver, that is one possibility, sound mix is a function of the driver.

Did you check to be sure there are no hidden devices in recording properties? Right click and select Show disabled devices. If stereo mix does not show after un hiding devices, then you cannot, it is disabled in the sound driver, if you updated the sound driver, roll it back to the old one using device manager, reboot. If stereo mix does show in there, right click on it and set as default.

.
[image]